# Dart : Parse object of Generic type

Tags: flutter, dart

Response 1:

```
{
   "status" :"ok",
   "message":"found",
   "data" : {
        "key1" :"value1",
        "key2" :"value2"
   }
  
}
```

Response 2 :

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "message": "found",
  "data": {
    "users": [
      {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Want to achieve for creating common class with type T.

it can be parsed like this :

```
Common<List<Data>> commonRes = Common<List<Data>>.fromJson(jsonDecode(res.body));
```

or

```
Common<Data> commonRes = Common<Data>.fromJson(jsonDecode(res.body));
```

Wanted to achieve same as java generic type `T`.

Anyone knows how to achieve this in dart ?

Tried to create common class like this. but, no luck.

```
class Common<T> {
  String? status;
  String? message;
  T? data;

  Common({
    this.status,
    this.message,
    this.data,
  });

  Common.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json['status'];
    message = json['message'];
    data = json['data'] as T;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data1 = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data1['status'] = this.status;
    data1['message'] = this.message;
    data1['data'] = this.data;

    return data1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It becomes apparent rather quickly that what you were trying to do is impossible, as dart has no idea how to convert `json['data']` to `T` and it can't know, a similar thing is the case in the `toJson()` function.
Usually the way to solve this is by helping them out and providing generator functions, which some of the code generator libraries also do, which I would suggest checking out. Anyway, here is the general idea behind it if you want to implement it yourself, but I recommend using a codegen library as this gets pretty old rather quickly once you have many API calls etc.

```
import 'dart:convert';

class Common<T> {
  String? status;
  String? message;
  T? data;

  Common({
    this.status,
    this.message,
    this.data,
  });

  Common.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json, T Function(Map<String, dynamic>) fromTJSON) {
    status = json['status'];
    message = json['message'];
    data = fromTJSON(json['data']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson(Map<String, dynamic> Function(T?) toTJSON) {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data1 = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data1['status'] = status;
    data1['message'] = message;
    data1['data'] = toTJSON(data);

    return data1;
  }
}


class ClassA {
  String? a;

  ClassA({this.a});

  ClassA.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    a = json['a'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data1 = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data1['a'] = a;
    return data1;
  }
}

class ClassB {
  String? b;

  ClassB({this.b});

  ClassB.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    b = json['b'];
  }
  
  static ClassB? generatorFoo(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data1 = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data1['b'] = b;
    return data1;
  }
}

int main() {
  String c1JSON = '''
  {
   "status" :"ok",
   "message":"found",
   "data" : {
        "a" :"someA"
   }
  
}
  ''';
   String c2JSON = '''
  {
   "status" :"ok",
   "message":"found",
   "data" : {
        "b" :"someb"
   }
  
}
  ''';
  Map<String,dynamic> map1 = jsonDecode(c1JSON);

  Common<ClassA> cA = Common.fromJson(map1, (map) => ClassA.fromJson(map));
  print(cA.toJson((obj) => obj != null ? obj.toJson() : {}));
  
  Map<String,dynamic> map2 = jsonDecode(c2JSON);

  Common<ClassB> cB = Common.fromJson(map2, (map) => ClassB.fromJson(map));
  print(cB.toJson((obj) => obj != null ? obj.toJson() : {}));
  return 0;
}
```

In your case you will also need to write a function to help with the mapping of the lists, the general idea is to provide a generator function so you can encode and decode the nested generic types.